# Apache Pig Load Function Bag as input possible?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

if I write a custom Load Function with the constructor

```
MyLoadFunction(String someOptions, DataBag myBag)
```

How can I execute this function with piglatin?

```
X = load 'foo.txt' using MyLoadFunction('myString', myBagAlias);
```

this does not work, is it even possible?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? (What is your input?)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354115/pig-latin-program-with-special-load-function ... My input is a HBase Table row. In this row is a map of columnnames. I transform this map into a bag. The names in this bag are rowkeys for another table. Now I try to get for every name the relevant row in the hbase database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your need is suitable for Pig.  Pig is all about loading up a lot of data and then putting that data through a pipeline.  It sounds like you want something more procedural, to load a small amount of data, do some processing, make a decision based on that, and follow that algorithm to completion.

So I'm not sure this is the best way for you to go, but you can try writing a UDF that will access HBase and grab the data you need.  `LOAD` is inappropriate here because `LOAD` does not return a bag, it returns a relation that Pig expects you to put through some transformations.  But you can pass a bag as input to a UDF, and then inside that UDF to do the HBase lookup and processing you want to do.

A more Pig-ish way of doing things would be to load all of the relevant HBase data into one or more relations, and then do a `JOIN` as appropriate to combine the pieces of data you want together.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. I tried to build my own UDF. Inside the UDF I used the hbase api to get the relevant row/columns, but I had really strange errors for example the UDF is only procede some items of the bag. I think you are right about it's not the best idea using the UDF here.